# Different font sizes of the odd and even pages numbers in amsbook

Tags: page-numbering, amsbook

I have an issue with the font sizes of the page numbers in `amsbook`. With the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\section*{Summary}

\pagestyle{myheadings} 
\makeatletter
\markboth{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont Summary}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont Summary}
\makeatother
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

the font size of the odd pages numbers is bigger, as in the figs. below.

And I really don't know how to make smaller the odd numbers, like the even numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you should not have formatting in `\markboth` but if you do use `{.....}` so the scope is just the word you want small, also you could use `\small` to get 10pt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, but I only want to decrease the size of the odd page numbers.

Comment: oh I see. Take the font change out of `\markboth` then use `fancyhdr` package to specify the whole page head is `\small`

Comment: Like this ? `\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\begin{document}

\section*{Summary}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeatletter
\markboth{Summary}{Summary}
\makeatother

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}`

Comment: I you would write the code, it would be great, since I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amsbook sets headings at `\scriptsize` and it seems you want 10pt, which is `\small`.

The simplest way is to copy the definition from `amsbook` and change `\scriptsize`. It then applies to both the head text and the page numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{\ps@empty
  \def\@evenhead{%
    \setTrue{runhead}%
    \normalfont\small% was\scriptsize
    \rlap{\thepage}\hfil
    \def\thanks{\protect\thanks@warning}%
    \leftmark{}{}\hfil}%
  \def\@oddhead{%
    \setTrue{runhead}%
    \normalfont\small \hfil % was\scriptsize
    \def\thanks{\protect\thanks@warning}%
    \rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\thepage}}%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\partmark{\@secmark\markboth\partrunhead\partname}%
  \def\chaptermark{%
    \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
  \def\sectionmark{%
    \@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\sectionname}%
}

\addtolength\headheight{2pt} % as font 10pt not 8pt

\setlength\textheight{\dimexpr\topskip+44\baselineskip}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section*{Summary}

\pagestyle{myheadings} 
\makeatletter
\markboth{SummaryA\expandafter\meaning\the\font}{Summary\the\font}
\makeatother
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well.